# Use PyDrive to upload files to Google Drive folder

Tags: python

I'm using PyDrive to upload files to Google Drive but could not figure out how to define the destination folder.

The following code saves a copy to the root on GDrive:

```
gauth = GoogleAuth() 
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
file1 = drive.CreateFile({'parent': '/home/pi'}) 
file1.SetContentFile('test.txt')
file1.Upload()
```

And how PyDrive returns the upload/download result?

Answer (score 6):

First you need to obtain the id of the parent folder (the one you want to place files into).  Use this code to do so:

```
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file1 in file_list:       
    print ('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))
sys.exit()
```

save the folder id in a variable:

```
fid = '...'
```

Then, to add to the folder corresponding to that id, the client code is:

```
f = drive.CreateFile({"parents": [{"kind": "drive#fileLink", "id": fid}]})
f.SetContentFile( some_path )
f.Upload()
```

You can get some info about the result:

```
print 'Created file %s with mimeType %s' % (f['title'], f['mimeType'])
```

Comment: This answer shows how to upload a file to a specific folder, which is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Where did you find the ""'root' in parents and trashed=false"" ?

Comment: @Alex75 it's part of the query language. You can find examples here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files#query_string_examples. I am wondering if there are keywords other than "root".

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

f = drive.CreateFile()
f.SetContentFile('document.txt')
f.Upload()
print('title: %s, mimeType: %s' % (f['title'], f['mimeType']))

file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file1 in file_list:
  print('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this,,

file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': YOUR_FILE_NAME, 'parents': [{'id': ['YOUR_GOOGLE_FOLDER_ID']}]})

Answer (score 0):

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)


folderName = 'FOLDER NAME'  # Please set the folder name.

folders = drive.ListFile(
    {'q': "title='" + folderName + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for folder in folders:
    if folder['title'] == folderName:
        file2 = drive.CreateFile({'title':'teste.txt','parents': [{'id': folder['id']}]})
        file2.Upload()
```

Comment: The official language of this site is English, not Python.

Comment: Please add a description to the code, not only the code.